How can I handle inconsistent JSON response structure in Dart?
I am calling one notification API. As a response of that API, I am getting one object, and in that object, I have one key called details. The issue is for a few, I am getting details as:
"{'comment':'comment', 'id':'this is id', 'commentText':'text}"

and for a few, I am getting "this is text". I am not getting comment, id, and commentText.
This is the bloc code:
 on<FetchNotifications>((event, emit) async {
      add(Refresh());
      final notifcationsList =
          await notificationRepositoryImpl.getNotifications();
      emit(NotificationFetched(notifications: notifcationsList!.data));
    });`
and this is impl code 
Future<NotificationResponse?> getNotifications() async {
    try {
      final response = await apiManager.getNotifications();
      final notificationList = NotificationResponse.fromJson(response.body);
      return notificationList;
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

and this the model:
import 'dart:convert';

NotificationResponse notificationResponseFromJson(String str) =>
    NotificationResponse.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String notificationResponseToJson(NotificationResponse data) =>
    json.encode(data.toJson());

class NotificationResponse {
  String message;
  bool success;
  List<Notification> data;

  NotificationResponse({
    required this.message,
    required this.success,
    required this.data,
  });

  factory NotificationResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      NotificationResponse(
        message: json["message"],
        success: json["success"],
        data: List<Notification>.from(
            json["data"].map((x) => Notification.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "message": message,
        "success": success,
        "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Notification {
  int id;
  String type;
  bool read;
  bool isDeleted;
  String details;
  int inspectorId;
  String createdBy;
  DateTime createdOn;
  dynamic modifiedBy;
  dynamic modifiedOn;

  Notification({
    required this.id,
    required this.type,
    required this.read,
    required this.isDeleted,
    required this.details,
    required this.inspectorId,
    required this.createdBy,
    required this.createdOn,
    this.modifiedBy,
    this.modifiedOn,
  });

  factory Notification.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Notification(
        id: json["id"],
        type: json["type"],
        read: json["read"],
        isDeleted: json["isDeleted"],
        details: json["details"],
        inspectorId: json["inspectorId"],
        createdBy: json["createdBy"],
        createdOn: DateTime.parse(json["createdOn"]),
        modifiedBy: json["modifiedBy"],
        modifiedOn: json["modifiedOn"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "type": type,
        "read": read,
        "isDeleted": isDeleted,
        "details": details,
        "inspectorId": inspectorId,
        "createdBy": createdBy,
        "createdOn": createdOn.toIso8601String(),
        "modifiedBy": modifiedBy,
        "modifiedOn": modifiedOn,
      };
}

